# Find $k$ shortest paths in linear time

Tags: algorithms

Suppose given number $k$ and undirected unweighted graph $G=(V,E)$, also given two vertices $s$ and $t$. Can we find $k$ shortest paths between $s$ and $t$ in $O(n+m)$ without term $k$?

I read this [link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/60368/linear-time-algorithm-for-finding-k-shortest-paths-in-unweighted-graphs) but I can't findout the answer of my question. I think this problem can't solve in polytime.

Comment: What are $n$ and $m$ ?

Comment: You obviously cannot report the $k$ shortest paths in less than $O(k)$ operations.

Comment: According to the linked question it is possible to do it in $O(n+m+k)$ time (since you did not rule out non-simple paths), which under assumption that $k=O(\max(n, m))$ gives $O(m+n)$ bound. But it is for unweighted graphs.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The output needs to be of length at least $k$, so you obviously need at least $k$ time steps even just to print the output.

To give yourself some intuition: imagine the case where $n=100$, $m=100$, and $k=$ a gazillion.  Are you really expecting an efficient algorithm that takes only a few hundred steps for that case?

Comment: What would be interesting, though, is finding an upper bound on $k$ given $n$ and $m$ (since the number of simple paths is finite in any graph, so is the number of shortest paths). Since in a complete graph or in a tree the number of shortest paths is exactly one, the worst graph is somewhere in between (I found a graph with a number of shortest path roughly $\sqrt{n}^{\sqrt{n}}$).

Comment: @Nathaniel k shortest paths problem does not care if k-th path is longer than the shortest path. Therefore I think the complete graph still is a contender for the hardest type of instances. Although, I am thinking about how hard the decision variant of the problem is, or even without k: "is the median path length between vertices $a$ and $b$ greater than $l$?"

Comment: @rus9384 While it is clear in the linked post, it was not that clear for me in this post, as I did not know this particular problem, thanks for noting it.